# fetch the metadata of a custom object in a apex class

Tags: metadata

my question is, is there any way to create a apex class which fetches the details of validations ,datatypes and other info. of the fields related to a particular custom object and display them in a visual force page.

Comment: Information about custom objects can be obtained in Apex as described in [Understanding Apex Describe Information](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm) and then presented using Visualforce.

Comment: thanks Keith, but i need some more details . i am new to salesforce and finding it difficult to implement your solution. so it would be helpful if you can provide me a working class code.

Comment: See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic controller that gets information about the fields of an object (`Contact` in this case):

```
public with sharing class DescribeController {

    public DescribeFieldResult[] getFieldDescribes() {

        DescribeFieldResult[] sobFieldDescribes = new DescribeFieldResult[] {};

        SObjectType sobType = Contact.SObjectType;
        DescribeSObjectResult sobDescribe = sobType.getDescribe();

        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fields = sobDescribe.fields.getMap();
        for (SObjectField sobField : fields.values()) {
            DescribeFieldResult sobFieldDescribe = sobField.getDescribe();
            sobFieldDescribes.add(sobFieldDescribe);
        }

        return sobFieldDescribes;
    }
}
```

and then a page like this can display the values returned by any of the get methods documented here [DescribeFieldResult Class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe) by just dropping the "get":

```
<apex:page controller="DescribeController">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!fieldDescribes}" var="d">
            <apex:column headerValue="Label" value="{!d.label}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!d.name}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Type" value="{!d.type}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: thanks keith for the reply. but i have already tried it. i think it doesnt fetch the validation rules.   the problem is i need validation rules also to be fetched in a apex class.

Comment: @YogeshGoad OK. Then you will have to also use the Metadata API from Apex. This is a good starting pint - https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi.